# Magento install errors

Tags: php, magento

I try to install new magento version 1.4.xx . But after the config menu I meet after I copy and change local.example.xml to local.xml .

```
Error in file: "E:\Soft\Programming\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\sql\catalog_setup\mysql4-install-1.4.0.0.0.php" - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4-page_layout' for key 'entity_type_id'

Trace:
#0 E:\Soft\Programming\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(374): Mage::exception('Mage_Core', 'Error in file: ...')
#1 E:\Soft\Programming\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(260): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_modifyResourceDb('install', '', '1.4.0.0.21')
#2 E:\Soft\Programming\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(224): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->_installResourceDb('1.4.0.0.21')
#3 E:\Soft\Programming\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Setup.php(153): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup->applyUpdates()
#4 E:\Soft\Programming\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(363): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup::applyAllUpdates()
#5 E:\Soft\Programming\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(295): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#6 E:\Soft\Programming\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\Mage.php(596): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 E:\Soft\Programming\xampp\htdocs\magento\index.php(78): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}
```

I really need your help , thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Lot's of folks have this problem when adding sample data. You can probably fix the problem by cleaning out the magento system logs

1. Log in as administrator
2. System -> Configuration -> System (under ‘Advanced’, bottom left) -> Log Cleaning

If you get the error again, hit the back button a few times and then try to recreate the error.

Comment: I just install it the first time . I don't even know the link to admin :|

Answer (score 0):

1) Why are you copying local.example.xml to local.xml - this is usually best done by the installer?
2) Are you importing sample data first or is it a clean install?